# C# How to display all instances of a loop in a label?

Tags: c#

So I'm trying to make a program to display prime numbers. The user inputs two numbers, the start and the end, and the program displays all of the prime numbers between those two inputs. ALL of those prime numbers are then displayed on a label named **labelResult**. I've tried the code in the console and it displays all of the results properly, but when I do it in a form and try applying it to a label, it only displays the last prime number. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

```
namespace PrimeNumbers
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int num1, num2;
        int count1;

        count1 = Convert.ToInt16(txtStart.Text);
        num2 = Convert.ToInt16(txtEnd.Text);

        bool isPrime = true;

        for (num1 = count1; num1 <= num2; num1++)
        {
            for (int j = 2; j <= 150; j++)
            {
                if (num1 != j && num1 % j == 0)
                {
                    isPrime = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (isPrime)
            {
                lblResult.Text = Convert.ToString("" + num1 + "" + num1);
            }
            isPrime = true;
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: also to make things easier you should have added the values to a List<T> or a ListBox or MultiLined TextBox.. also you have the debugger at your disposal.. why are you not using it..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code will overwrite the value in each iteration of the loop. You need to append to the existing text to get your desired output. Further, rather than assign to the label each time, you may want to build your string of numbers first and then assign to the label, like so:

```
bool isPrime = true;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (num1 = count1; num1 <= num2; num1++)
    {
        for (int j = 2; j <= 150; j++)
        {
            if (num1 != j && num1 % j == 0)
            {
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (isPrime)
        {
            sb.Append("" + num1 + "" + num1);
        }
        isPrime = true;
    }
lblResult.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

Since when you run the loop and when the `isPrime` is true `lblResult` will get updated with the value. Next Time, Means on the next loop again the value get updated but would remove the last value. So in that case just say that You wanted to retain the last value + the new value.

```
lblResult.Text = lblResult.Text + Convert.ToString("" + num1 + "" + num1);
```

Answer (score 0):

A small Correction with exact result.

```
  int num1, num2;
        int count1;

        count1 = Convert.ToInt16(txtStart.Text);
        num2 = Convert.ToInt16(txtEnd.Text);            
        bool isPrime = true;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (num1 = count1; num1 <= num2; num1++)
        {
            for (int j = 2; j <= 150; j++)
            {
                if (num1 != j && num1 % j == 0)
                {
                    isPrime = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (isPrime)
            {
                sb.Append("," + num1);
            }
            isPrime = true;
        }
        lblResult.Text= sb.ToString().TrimStart(',');
```